# Passing JavaScript value to Ruby in ERB

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

I want to pass JavaScript value as a parameter to the Ruby Function in ERB.

Code for index.html.erb

```
function ABC(){
  variable = document.getElementById('textfield').value;
}

function XYZ(){
  <%= ruby_function(variable) %>
}
```

I need help inorder to achieve this.

Comment: You can't do that, you should make an ajax call to execute your ruby method with a js variable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Can you help me with AJAX call and how i should pass variable as a parameter.

Comment: Do you want to pass the variable to your HTML view? i.e.abc.html.erb?

Comment: Is it a Rails views?

Comment: What is your exact requirement?

Comment: Well, if your intention it's just set a javascript value they way you presented is perfectly fine. Javascript will be compiled after the server processed, so all ruby tags will be converted

Comment: @RonanLouarn this code is present in index.html.erb file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate way of achieving this is using ajax in your script.

For instance you can use coffee script and do the something like this.

```
ABC = ->
  variable = document.getElementById('textfield').value
  res = $.ajax(
    url: '#{method_controller_path}'
    method: 'GET'
    data:
      param: variable
    dataType: 'json'
    success: (res) ->
      res
  )
```

At the end you will have the *res* object to work with.

Incase you are not using coffee or external script files. You can do this using javascript in the index.html.erb file.

Here is an example for that.

```
const ABC = function() {
  let res;
  const variable = document.getElementById('textfield').value;
  return res = $.ajax({
    url: '#{method_controller_path}',
    method: 'GET',
    data: {
      param: variable
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success(res) {
      return res;
    }
  });
};
```

Hope this helps you out. :)

Comment: I want to keep ```function ABC()``` as separate and just need to pass the value as a parameter. So can you tell how I can use ajax to pass the value as a parameter

Comment: Ajax will send a request to the route you use in _url_ property. So the ruby method you use against that route will receive the value as a request parameter. 

You will have to permit those values in your controller and then use those as required.

Answer (score 0):

This one sould works without Jquery.

ruby controller:

```
class MyServiceController
  def variable
    @var = ruby_function(params[:js_var])
    responde_to do |format|
      format.js { render json: @var }
    end
  end
end
```

js function:

```
  function XYZ(){
    var variable = document.getElementById('textfield').value;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.open('POST', 'myservice/variable');
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var rubyResponse = xhr.responseText;
    };
    xhr.send(encodeURI('js_var=' + variable));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ERB(embedded ruby) if you write it inside a script tag in the html and the file is an ERB file. The example of the ruby code in this javascript is benign but illustrates how you can do this.

```
<body>
  <%= render 'shared/overlay' %>
  <%= render 'shared/notice_alert_modals' %>
  <header>
    <%= image_tag header_logo, class: 'logo' %>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      // append some tag with erb ruby
      var html = "<h2>ABC<%= %w[D E F].split(' ').join %></h2>"
      $('body').append(html)
    })
  </script>
</body>
```